# Can table parameters be null in a stored procedure and how can I test for inclusion of an item

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datatable

I have a stored proc in SQL Server that accepts a table (dataset) as a parameter like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[blah]
(
    @someParm INT,
    @someTableParm [dbo].[IntIdType] READONLY,
```

The type IntIdType is like this:

```
 CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntIdType] AS TABLE(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL
 )
```

But I need to be able to test to see if the parameter passed is NULL or if it can even be passed as null, and if not, I need to make a special test if it contains zero items

```
WHERE [SomeParm] = 2 AND
(@someTableParm IS NULL OR EXISTS (SELECT something FROM @someTableParm)) AND ...
```

I get the error message: Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure xxxx, Line 58 [Batch Start Line 0]
Must declare the scalar variable "@someTableParm".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`@someTableParm IS NULL` would look for a scalar variable `@someTableParm`, but your variable a table, so that won't work. Therefore, stick to `EXISTS`:

```
WHERE [SomeParm] = 2
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @someTableParm)
  AND...
```

If there are no rows in `@someTableParm`, then the `EXISTS` will return false. As a quick sample:

```
CREATE TABLE test (ID int)
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1);

DECLARE @S table (I int);

SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @S);

DROP TABLE test;
```

Notice that the `SELECT` statement returns no rows.

Comment: Adding that an explict NULL cannot be passed as a TVP parameter value. The TVP will be empty if the parameter is not specified.